# Magento REST Customer API not working

Tags: magento, rest

I have tried the sample code “oauth_customer.php” from below documentation:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction_to_rest_api
Please see the heading:  “Retrieve the list of products as a Customer user with OAuth authentication”

But, when I tried to access the page, it seems works fine, but I didn't get the product list array as expected!; instead it just redirected to customer account page in magento.
The steps followed:
1) Set up the consumer key, consumer secret etc.
2)Accessed the page through browser: http://myhost.com/oauth_customer.php
3)Asked for customer login credentials and then clicked “Authorize” button.
4)Page redirected to customer account page.

Why I am not getting the product list array ? Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Iqbal.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the callback URL to the same as the page running the script.